# Lagging financial data in R data table

Tags: r

I have a data set containing serveral financial data, including some fundamentals. For example, I got debt data from April, but it actually should be lets say Dec. As they are released at a later point in time, i have to lag them back for appr. 4 monhts.

This is what my data looks like (illustration)

```
k <- c("gvkey1" , "gvkey1" , "gvkey1" , "gvkey1", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey2", "gvkey3", "gvkey3")

l <- c("Date1", "Date2", "Date3", "Date4" , "Date5" , "Date6" , "Date7" , "Date8" , "Date9" , "Date10" , "Date11" )
m <- c(1:11)

y <- structure(list(a = l, b = k, c = m), .Names = c("Date", "gvkey" , "DLCQ"),
               row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
     Date  gvkey DLCQ
1   Date1 gvkey1    1
2   Date2 gvkey1    2
3   Date3 gvkey1    3
4   Date4 gvkey1    4
5   Date5 gvkey2    5
6   Date6 gvkey2    6
7   Date7 gvkey2    7
8   Date8 gvkey2    8
9   Date9 gvkey2    9
10 Date10 gvkey3   10
11 Date11 gvkey3   11
```

and this is the code I already tried:

```
x <- shift(y$DLCQ, 4L)
```

However, this gives me back one single vector and basically "deletes" all the other columns (date, gvkey).

```
[1] NA NA NA NA  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

It should look like something like this:

```
     Date  gvkey DLCQ
1   Date1 gvkey1    NA
2   Date2 gvkey1    NA
3   Date3 gvkey1    NA
4   Date4 gvkey1    NA
5   Date5 gvkey2    1
6   Date6 gvkey2    2
7   Date7 gvkey2    3
8   Date8 gvkey2    4
9   Date9 gvkey2    5
10 Date10 gvkey3    6
11 Date11 gvkey3    7
```

Moreover, since my data is in long format, the code should run for each gvkey separately (e.g. with ,by =gvkey).

Thanks
Johannes

Comment: Please show the code of your attempt.

Comment: Please make the question *reproducible*. This includes sample code (including listing non-base R packages) (GG suggested this), sample *unambiguous* data (e.g., `dput(head(x))`, preferably as something I can use easily and not HTML-encumbered), and your expected output. It really helps to show what effort you've put in, both so that we see your focus and can tailor answers to your style, and also to show that you are putting in non-zero effort before asking here. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.